# Python QtCore.Object Baseclass inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, pyside, qtcore

I've searched around online for the answer however I was not entirely clear on the content i was readying so i figured i would post it here.

I wanted to know if the way I'm creating a class inheriting from Baker is being done correctly.

Say I have a base class:

```
class Baker(QtCore.QObject):

    changedProperty = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
        ...
```

Then I create classes based off of Baker like this:

```
class NormalBaker(Baker):
    def __init__(self):
        Baker.__init__(self, name='Normal Baker')
        ...
```

is this correct?

**UPDATED**

Is this snippet of code the proper way to subclass from Baker?

```
def __init__(self):
     Baker.__init__(self, name='Normal Baker')
```

Comment: If it is correct, why the question? Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: What was this "content I was reading" that you found unclear? A few links could have made your question a lot easier to understand.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: @JokerMartini *Is this snippet of code the proper way to subclass from Baker?* 
Yes, that's right, you're passing the father's constructor what he needs. Why the doubt?

Comment: @eyllanesc Was not sure if i should be using this:

super(Baker, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: @JokerMartini There are 2 styles of calling the father, `Baker.__init__(self, name='Normal Baker')` is equivalent to `super(Baker, self).__init__(name='Normal Baker) ` in the case that only a class is inherited as is your case.

Comment: @JokerMartini see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods